# Error SoftLayer_Product_Order. (SoftLayer_Product_Order:: verifyOrder)

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ims

I am having trouble with the modifyContact call. Every time I try to execute it I receive the error:

```
{
    "error": "Invalid container specified: SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order. Ordering a server or service requires a specific container type, not the generic base order container.",
    "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidContainer"
}
```

**URL**

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json

**CURL Request**

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "location": "DALLAS09",
            "packageId": 10,
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "orderOrigin",
                    "value": "control"
                }
            ],
            "hardware": [
                {
                    "hostname": "vsiHostname",
                    "domain": "domain.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following payload:

```
{
"parameters": [
    {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Software_Component_Virtual",
        "hardware": [
        {
           "domain": "domain.com",
           "hostname": "vsiHostname"
        }
          ],
       "location": "448994",
       "packageId": 10,
       "prices": [
            {"id": 242840,
             "item": {
                  "description": "cPanel/WHM with Fantastico and RVskin Premier Cloud up to 100 Accounts",
                  "id": 14292
              }
            }
        ],
      "endPointIpAddressIds":[1111111],
      "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

}

Replace the 1111111 for your ipAddressId.

Comment: Hi @F.Ojeda . I am getting an error : {
    "error": "Invalid price Account Setup Fee (1798) provided on the order container.",
    "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid"
}